# Enforce Entra ID conditional Access policies based in specific Graph Claim value asked by application

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

*Introduction:*

There is an application "**App**" registered in an external Azure tenant (**ExternalTenant**) that my users log in using their tenant (**InternalTenant**) email.

This application allows anyone to log in, but requests Permission consent to "Read email calendar events", to synchronize the user Exchange Calendar with the **App** internal calendar events.

My users (assuming they have a License that gives them a Mailbox/Calendar) can allow this consent and then use the application normally.

I'm currently playing with EntraID Conditional Access, and I have made a couple of policies to restrict which users can use the **App**
[image: Conditinal Access]

Inside the policies I have selected the **App** in Target Resources, and then made some test conditions to filter access by OS.

This has worked great, but my next step is to enforce a more granular permission.

I want that all users can log into the app, but restrict which of them can pass the
*Calendars.ReadWrite* claim value

[image]

Ideally, I would like to enforce MFA when this specific claim is asked, but to allow non-MFA login when this isn't asked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: You cannot configure conditional access policy based on the specific graph claim.

- Conditional Access policies primarily focus on controlling access based on factors such as user, device, location, and application, rather than specific claims or permissions requested by the application
- You can create policy in the application level but not possible to enforce a policy with granular permission.

You can select the applications:

[image]

And the conditions are like below, you cannot configure the condition based on the claim:

[image]

*Hence, you cannot configure the policy with the specific claim.*

- The API permissions granted are tenant wide and cannot be restricted.

**Reference:**

[Building a Conditional Access policy - Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-policies)